# How to make web_ui compile css files automatically

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I'm using web_ui and whenever I change a CSS file in `web/css/` it will not be compiled unless I change the `web/index.html` file. I guess that's because only the file 'web/index.html' is listed as entry point in build.dart.

But adding the stylesheet to the entry points list didn't work.

Is there a way to autocompile CSS files every time they are changed without having to edit the `.html` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that you can edit any `.dart` or `.html` file and the compiler will run; it doesn't have to be the entry point file.

Autocompilation of CSS files on change can be achieved by passing the compiler the `full` flag:

```dart
build(['--machine', '--full'], ['web/index.html']);
```

The `machine` flag tells the compiler to print messages to the Dart Editor console. For a full list of flags see [Build.dart and the Dart Editor Build System](http://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/build.html).

This method means that every time a file is changed your entire project will be rebuilt instead of the usual incremental approach. If you have a large project this may take a while. Here is a more comprehensive build file that takes advantage of incremental compilation and only rebuilds the whole project if a css file was changed:

```dart
List<String> args = new Options().arguments;
bool fullRebuild = false;

for (String arg in args) {
  if (arg.startsWith('--changed=') && arg.endsWith('.css')) {
    fullRebuild = true;
  }
}

if(fullRebuild) {
  build(['--machine', '--full'], ['web/index.html']);
} else {
  build(args, ['web/index.html']);
}
```